# Gridview with multiple elements in each row

Tags: c#, json, windows-8, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

There is an app which has the listbox with multiple rows and there is some info in each of this rows. How to implement that? Try to use gridview in listbox?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest way to replicate this

1. Create a new Store App with Grid App Template
2. Replace the GridView code with this

   ```
       <ListView.ItemsPanel>
           <ItemsPanelTemplate>                        
               <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
           </ItemsPanelTemplate>
       </ListView.ItemsPanel>
       <ListView.GroupStyle>
           <GroupStyle>
               <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                   <DataTemplate>
                       <Grid Margin="1,0,0,6">
                           <Button
                               AutomationProperties.Name="Group Title"
                               Click="Header_Click"
                               Style="{StaticResource TextPrimaryButtonStyle}" >
                               <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                   <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Margin="3,-7,10,10" Style="{StaticResource GroupHeaderTextStyle}" />
                                   <TextBlock Text="{StaticResource ChevronGlyph}" FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol" Margin="0,-7,0,10" Style="{StaticResource GroupHeaderTextStyle}"/>
                               </StackPanel>
                           </Button>
                       </Grid>
                   </DataTemplate>
               </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
               <GroupStyle.Panel>
                   <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                       <VariableSizedWrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,80,0"/>
                   </ItemsPanelTemplate>
               </GroupStyle.Panel>
           </GroupStyle>
       </ListView.GroupStyle>
   </ListView>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

It's a grouped `GridView`. You should set `ItemsPanel` of `GridView` as `VirtualizingStackPanel` with vertical orientation.

Check out [Grouping GridView on Windows 8](http://weblogs.asp.net/nmarun/archive/2012/09/15/grouping-gridview-on-windows-8.aspx)